# Benefits of running an asynchronous method on a different thread? (C#)

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I came across these statements in a project that I am maintaining:

```
var response = Task.Run(() =>
{
    return httpClient.PostAsync(myUrl, myPayload);
}).Result;
```

It runs, on a different thread, an asynchronous method to make an HTTP request.

Unless I am missing something, is there any additional benefit in running an asynchronous method on a different thread? Wouldn't this be good enough?

```
var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(myUrl, myPayload);
```

Comment: Since `Task.Run` isn't awaited I asume that the containing methode isn't declared async...?

Comment: In the first case, since you're using `.Result`, you're also blocking the calling thread, so that code is not really asynchronous

Comment: @Ackdari, that is correct, that code is in a function that is not declared `async`.

Comment: I would asume that this was an attempt for stopping async/await from spreding to the whole codebase

Comment: @Ackdari, thank you for confirming the suspicion. I also believe that it was an attempt to make all methods async.

Comment: @user11081980 No - it's the opposite.  This code means you don't need to mark the containing method as async, and the methods that call that etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Unless I am missing something, is there any additional benefit in running an asynchronous method on a different thread?

The existing code doesn't just use `Task.Run`; it uses `Task.Run` *and then blocks on the resulting task*. This is a variant of the "[thread pool hack](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt238404.aspx)" which is one way to block on asynchronous code. Although the code should be using `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` rather than `Result`.

Many libraries support blocking directly rather than requiring the thread pool hack. `HttpClient` in particular mostly does, but there are some platforms (mobile platforms, IIRC) where `HttpClient` had a bug where you couldn't block directly on it. So it's most likely that this code is intended as a "blocking hack".

---

There is another reason for running an asynchronous method on a thread pool thread: if that thread does some synchronous work. Again, this is a known issue with `HttpClient`; the proxy resolution and DNS lookup is done synchronously. If the existing code was `await Task.Run(() => ...);` instead of `Task.Run(() => ...).Result;`, then I would think this alternative explanation would be more likely.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you understand your first example use `.Result` which is blocking and second using `await` do not.

Now to answer your question -

> It runs, on a different thread, an asynchronous method to make an HTTP request.
>
> Unless I am missing something, is there any additional benefit in running an asynchronous method on a different thread? Wouldn't this be good enough?

**There is no benefit in blocking an additional thread just to wait for the `POST` call to return data.**

And yes this is recommended way of doing it -

```
 var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(myUrl, myPayload);
```

You can read more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async)